# How do I check which of the 12 Brothersisterpon I've found?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

In the Central Exchange of the Argentum Trade Guild, the owner of the 12 Brothersisterpon shop asks you to find his 11 brothers and sisters. I think I've found most of them, but I can't figure out who is missing.

Is there any way to check which siblings I've found already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to check which siblings you've found already. From the [Xenoblade Wiki](https://xenoblade.fandom.com/wiki/Twelve_Brothersisterpon):

> Twelve Brothersisterpon is an informal quest in Xenoblade Chronicles 2. It does not appear in the quest log. It is initiated by speaking to Motata at the 12 Brothersisterpon shop in Argentum. **Since it does not appear in the quest log, there is no way to check one's progress.**

Your only option is to [check every sibling's location](https://xenoblade.fandom.com/wiki/Twelve_Brothersisterpon) to see which ones you missed.